# Localization issue when site in read-only mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, russian-stackoverflow, read-only

A couple days ago SE sites went into read-only mode. In particular for Stack Overflow in Russian we got a unlocalized messages:

> [image: read-only]

Top message, `Login` and `XOXO` should be available to localize.

Comment: You have a Russian translation for XOXO?

Comment: @rene I don't know what is it, screenshot is not mine. If you have English version of this message we could compare them. I hope developers know what is it actually.

Comment: It is internet slang for Kiss and Hugs: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=xoxo

Comment: @rene I didn't know before. I think if it will be able to localize, we can find something Russian specific.

Comment: @rene translation has been selected [here](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4720/176217).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These strings will be in Transifex whenever the strings are imported from Q&A next time: `Login` (which may already be there? not sure off the top of my head) and `XOXO,`.

Comment: What about the read only banner? I think that's the main issue reported here as it's more than just a single word.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Whoops, you're right. I completely missed that. Will look again on Monday.

Comment: Still can't find strings from the top banner in transifex.

Comment: @alexolut Yeah, turns out that banner comes from a spot that needs some special care. I have a change ready that *should* enable localization, but I need to run it by a couple other people for review.